# Make PermissionRequiredMixin also check for object level permission

Tags: django, django-permissions, django-guardian

I am using `Django Guardian` to have object-level permission along with global permissions. Some of the users have a group with global permissions, and some have object-level permissions. With this, I seem to need to modify the `PermissionRequiredMixin` to check also for the object-level permission.

`views.py`

```
class MainPageView(PermissionRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    permission_required = "app.view_mainpage"
    template_name = "web/mainpage.html"
```

This one works if the user has global permission but if the user is under a group with object-level permission, it won't. With guardian, to check for object-level permission, you also have to pass the object instance.

example:

```
self.request.user.has_perm('view_mainpage', obj)
```

And on `PermissionRequiredMixin`, the checking goes only like this, `self.request.user.has_perms(perms)`

So if the user has a group with permission of `view_mainpage` of a specific object, how can I check it too? By the way, all my permissions are of the same `content_type`. Is there any way I can execute this? Like I have to pass the object instance to `PermissionRequiredMixin` if the user is under an object-level group and `None` if the user is under a global group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement such mixin yourself with:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class ObjectPermissionRequiredMixin:
    object_permission_required = None
    object_permission_denied_message = None

    def has_object_permission(self, obj):
        return self.request.user.has_perm(self.object_permission_required, obj)

    def get_object_permission_denied_message(self):
        return self.object_permission_denied_message

    def handle_no_object_permission(self):
        raise PermissionDenied(self.get_object_permission_denied_message())

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super().get_object(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.has_object_permission(obj)
            return self.handle_no_object_permission()
        return obj
```

Then you can mix this mixin into a view, for example:

```
class MyUpdateView(ObjectPermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    object_permission_required = 'app.update_my_model'
    object_permission_denied_message = 'You can not edit this object'
```

This will work for all `View`s that usee the [**`SingleObjectMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin) such as a `DetailView`, `UpdateView`, and the `DeleteView`.

Comment: It worked! I just had some changes to get the object from a different source, but this solution worked! thanks!